# Генерация случайных цифр, сумма которых равна определенному числу

Tags: python

задача,(Python 3.3): сгенерировать определенное количество случайных цифр определенной суммы...

Этот код "не работает", но может помочь вам понять вопрос...

```
import random
d=input('Rabochie dni: ')
den=int(d)
p=input('Probeg: ')
pro=int(p)
sr=pro//den
sl=[]
while sum(sl)!=pro:
    for i in range(den):
        sls=random.randint(sr-10,sr+10)
        sl.append(sls)
print (sl)
```

Comment: Ну так и создавайте на одно значение меньше, чем нужно, а последнее значение будет равно:  

    sl.append(pro-sum(sl))

Answer (score 1):

В Python'е не силён, но могу посоветовать такой алгоритм:

1. Генрим n случайных чисел (без каких-либо ограничений)
2. Находим их сумму `randSum`
3. Находим коэффициент масштабирования `scale = randSum / sum` (`sum` - необходимая сумма)
4. Каждое сгенеренное число делим на `scale`, округляя вверх
5. Пересчитываем сумму получившихся чисел, если она больше `sum`, то уменьшаем одно из чисел.

Comment: у меня случайные цифра без ограничений выходят только между 0 и 1. типа 0.002124512. это нормально? и я как то не смог сделать по вашему...

Answer (score 1):

```
list = []
sumcontrol = 0

average = sum//n

while (1 < n)
    list += random.randint(1,average)
    sumcontrol += list (n)
    n --

list += abs(sum-sumcontrol)
```

не расчитан для отрицательных чисел.

Answer (score 0):

Только для целых чисел:

```
import random

total = 200 # общая сумма
n = 5 # количество чисел

my_total = -1
while my_total != total:
    nums = [random.randint(0,total) for _ in range(n)]
    my_total = sum(nums)

print(nums)
```

Можем использовать доступный диапазон чисел от -(2 ^ 31) + 1 до 2 ^ 31 - 1

```
import random

total = 200
n = 5

my_total = -1
while my_total != total:
    nums = [random.randint(-(2 ** 31 + 1), (2 ** 31 - 1)) for _ in range(n)]
    my_total = sum(nums)

print(nums)
```

Но у меня очень долго что либо генерировало, поэтому мне этот способ не кажется удачным